# Error when importing programs IDLE

Tags: python

Im new to Python but Im getting on pretty well, however I cannot seem to import save programs into IDLE. Could someone assist me where that is concerned, please. This is one of the errors no matter how simple the program is:

```
>>> import dinner

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    import dinner
  File "C:\Python25\dinner.py", line 1
    Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the error you would get if your `dinner.py` program actually started with the line

```
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

But that's not a line of valid Python code, that's the message that the interpreter gives on startup.  For example, mine says

```
~/coding$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

and it's then that I start typing things like `print 2+2`, etc.  You can open `dinner.py` in IDLE and remove any parts which look like this welcome message at the start.

Incidentally, I see you're using Python 2.5.4.  This is pretty old now, and a lot of neat things have been added since.  I would suggest switching to 2.7.3 instead.